# How much damage does the scythe do in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've been wondering for awhile how much damage the scythe does in Candy Box 2?

Answer (score 1):

The Scythe does 21 damage, seven times a second.

Answer (score 0):

The inventory screens shows you the damage that weapons do below the picture of the weapon:

[image: Screenshot of inventory screen with weapon-damage outlined]

Answer (score 0):

it only does 1 damage but if you go and enchant it (wishing well) than you can get 27 damage at incredibly fast and will knock enemies of their feet and will revive you 12 life at a time once you get to 12 life in battle

Answer (score 0):

The scythe does 21 damage. With the xinopherydon claw, it doubles the damage, causing it to do 42 damage.